# How to add a dynamic variable into a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, twitter-feed

I'm trying to modify a twitter widget where based on the dropdown, users can switch between the different search terms.

Instead of the present code where I have to define a keyword, I want to create a dropdown list of keywords so my users can select one and the relative tweets are shown. The Jquery I have in the head section is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tweets ul').twitterfeed('#keyword', {
        type: "query",
        count: 5
    })
});
```

And my select box code is:

```
<strong>Select your keyword</strong>:<select id="keyword">
<option value="ABC">ABC</option>
<option value="XYZ" selected="selected">XYZ</option>
</select>
```

Any help on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: No error at all. It doesn't display the feeds when I replace it with CarlosZ's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#keyword').change(function() {
        // in the even handler this points to the element that triggered it
        $('#tweets ul').twitterfeed($(this).val(), {
            type: "query",
            count: 5
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Carlos,Thanks for the quick response. I tried your code but nothing changed.. I can only see the drop down.. Is this got to do with the twitter.js script that is being called?

Comment: I have never used that plugin, you should make sure it is triggering an api call to twitter (use firebug).

Comment: Yep, the API call is being made from twitter.js. I think one possible reason could be because the script is being put in the header, while the select dropdown is on the body section?

Comment: No that's not it, by having the script wrapped in `$(document).ready` it will be executed only after the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Maybe I should include the <select> code within the form tag? If yes, then what would the form action and method be?

Comment: 1. I don't think you should post the feeds in a `ul` tag. 2. @CarlosZ has an extra `)` after `$(this).val()`. Removing it will fix the issue.

Comment: Brilliant.. this fixed the issue. Thanks a ton guys.. @Khez, what would be the alternative to the UL tag?

Comment: @Sledge81 any block-level element would be good, `DIV` is a popular choice for most things. `UL` is meant for lists, and it should hold `LI` tags. The twitterfeed plugin inserts divs, not list items.